# Identify Tan Solider caps

Tags: part-identification, minifigures

Cany anyone identify the small tan caps worn by the soldiers in [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEUna4lDNl8)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [cavalry cap](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30135), apparently also known as a kepi.